# How resolve Custom Filter issue

Tags: java, mysql, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I have create a report in myExtension-items-core.xml (that run a query where the condition is : "WHERE {bs.uid} in (?baseStorePk)") and I add a custom filter (BaseStore) in AdvancedSearch of an entity. Now when I click on button search (after choose the baseStore) I have this error in the log.[image]

[image]

The method into AdvancedSearchController:

```
public void myAddFilterQueryRawCondition ( final AdvancedSearchData searchData, final List models)
{
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(models) && models.stream().noneMatch(x -> !(x instanceof BaseStoreModel)))
{
        List<String> baseStorePk = ((List<BaseStoreModel>) models).stream()
                .map(bs -> bs.getUid())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
        fieldType.setDisabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        fieldType.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
        fieldType.setName("baseStorePk");

        searchData.addFilterQueryRawCondition(fieldType, ValueComparisonOperator.IN, baseStorePk);

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need custom filter ,please adjust query so that you need to select directly baseStore,

Comment: @RaushanKumar The task required a custom filter that oper a reference search and I choose 3 baseStore and the search starts by filtering those chosen stores

Comment: can you try this.
searchData.addCondition(fieldType, ValueComparisonOperator.IN, baseStorePk);

Comment: Hi ,@mike is it working now?

Comment: @RaushanKumar Hi yes work, but search only first element of the list. Exsample : if I have a sotre1, store2, strore3, the result if only for the store1.